# How can I dynamically assign elements of a list to cells meeting specific condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, data-science

I'm doing animal studies and using automated operant boxes that output massive csv files, I've got multiple animals running multiple sessions per day and so in order to make sense of my data I loop through multiple csv files and extract relevant data to a separate excel file. I managed to make almost all of the the code dynamic except for one crucial bit: I have to assign subject IDs to multiple ranges of rows that correspond to that subject's data.

The way I'm currently doing it is first extracting a list of [ID]'s of 16 subjects in the order the they were run on that day and then creating a new session order column in my dataframe that tells which session the data is for. Then I've made a blank 'ID' column to which I then manually assign each range of rows from session one to the first element in the [ID] list, then the session 2 to second element and so on, here is the code example:

```
df['ID'] = 0
df.at[(df['Session'] == 1), 'ID'] = ID[0]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 2), 'ID'] = ID[1]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 3), 'ID'] = ID[2]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 4), 'ID'] = ID[3]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 5), 'ID'] = ID[4]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 6), 'ID'] = ID[5]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 7), 'ID'] = ID[6]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 8), 'ID'] = ID[7]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 9), 'ID'] = ID[8]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 10), 'ID'] = ID[9]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 11), 'ID'] = ID[10]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 12), 'ID'] = ID[11]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 13), 'ID'] = ID[12]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 14), 'ID'] = ID[13]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 15), 'ID'] = ID[14]
df.at[(df['Session'] == 16), 'ID'] = ID[15]
```

Up to this point this served me well, however my n number has changed to 15, now I have a mixture of CSVs with different n numbers and I get the 'list index out of range' error soon as the loop reaches the n=15 file. Because of the nature of my work, it's very likely that the n number is going to change multiple times in the future so I want to adapt my code to accommodate that. My main issue is the fact that I'm not familiar with beyond basic Python's principles, reason being I needed to rapidly progress from not knowing how to code in any language to having developed my own script that is tailored to wacky CSVs, I decided I'll focus on understanding pandas and only learn the bits that are directly relevant to solving my immediate issues and unfortunately that came at a cost of not being equipped to solve issues like this one...

I've tried different things none of which worked so my question is how can I make this dynamic so that it  works with various n numbers?

Many many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just create a map from session number to ID.

Assuming your sessions will always be numbered starting at 1, this would work:

```
SESSION_ID = dict(enumerate(ID, 1))
```

Then simply:

```
df['ID'] = df['Session'].map(SESSION_ID)
```